# COUNTIF(LOOKUP) + on pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset with 30 million rows as a pandas Dataframe and I have created another df which should be a "summarized" table (groupby like) of the first one. The main dataframe has a column called 'HeadSecNum' with values from 0.0 to 15.0, and the second dataframe Id like to have a count of how may rows I have for each of these 0.0-15.0 numbers, on column 'Total Count'.

I tried something like that to match the rows but I can't find where and how should I put the .count() statement:

```
headingtable['Total Count'] = headingtable.apply(lambda x: data.loc[x['HeadSecNum'] == data['HeadSecNum'], x['HeadSecNum']].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
```

Obviously, this gives me a dimension error. Should I run a for statement with dataframes? Or is not necessary?

Summarized table setup:

```
headstruct={'HeadSecNum':[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],
              'Heading Sector':['N','NNE','NE','ENE','E','ESE','SE','SSE','S','SSW','SW','WSW','W','WNW','NW','NNW'],
              'Total Count':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              'PCT':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
headingtable=pd.DataFrame(data=headstruct)
print(headingtable)
```

Calculating the matching value at the database:

```
data=dl.dataload(r'NewBases/test.csv')
    ##calculate heading & wind direction sector
data['HeadSecNum']=np.round_(data['Heading']/22.5)
```

Comment: What is prohibiting you from using a groupby clause and then merging afterwards? Using an apply is not the best way to go about this

Comment: My very limited knowledge on pýthon lol. Ill google that and post a feedback thx